# Does the ItemCheckedIn event fire when item is updated?

Tags: event-receivers, check-in

I can't find any documentation on exactly when the ItemCheckedIn fires. I know it does when a user explicitly checkes it in, but I thought it would also fire when an item was added, or updated, since it actually is checked in then too.

When does it fire? Only when a user does the specific Check In command, or also when an item is implicitly checked in, for example added or updated?

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm working with remote event receivers

Answer (score 6):

Answer to your question yes it will fire ItemCheckedIn event, if inside Versioning settings link->The Require Check Out radio is selected.

Some more information:

ItemCheckedIn fires
1. once we add document, automatic checking will happen, which will fire ItemCheckedIn.
2. Next when we explicitly call ItemCheckedIn.

following sequence you may notice in event execution.

1.User clicks on the Add a Document link

2.SharePoint displays the Upload a Document dialog

3.User uploads the Document to SharePoint

4.SharePoint fires the **ItemAdding** Event

5.SharePoint adds the document to the Library

6.SharePoint fires the **ItemAdded** event

7.SharePoint displays the property editing screen to the user

8.User edits any properties they wish to change and clicks the Save button

9.SharePoint fires the **ItemUpdating** event (first time it is fired)

10.SharePoint sets any document property field entered in the property editor dialog

11.SharePoint fires the **ItemUpdated** event (first time it is fired)

12.SharePoint now begins the process of automatically checking in the document

13.SharePoint fires the **ItemUpdating** event (second time it is fired)

14.SharePoint fires the **ItemCheckingIn** event

15.SharePoint fires the **ItemUpdated** event (second time it is fired)

16.SharePoint fires the **ItemCheckedIn** event

Hope this will help.

Comment: if this is the life cycle of uploading a document, how can i change the modify by field in the item, from system account ---> to the one who modified by? this is the issue am facig. i have written inside a  itemupdated event handler and am getting the modified by as system account instead of the user account.